# Ajax Request Returning Response Header In Result In Google Chrome

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, request

I am getting Response Header on Ajax Request as a Result in Google Chrome for first time when request is sent, after this request ajax results correctly.
Requests is working fine all time in Mozilla Firefox.

Here is my Ajax code :

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "get_product_links.php?product_id="+productval,
    success: function(data){
        jQuery('#prodcut_links').html(data);
        jQuery('#product_title').hide();
    }
});
```

Result Response is (Error: Getting this result in  ) : 
�HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2013 03:04:28 GMT Server: Apache Vary: Accept-Encoding Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Length: 525 Connection: close Content-Type: text/html ���Mo�0������0%��ر�n��k�^z,dYN�ْ!)u��G�YPt���I�߇�p�e����Fd�2.-�.�����Ee�i�l�s�T�t�)�u��P�ʳ��p��AY�L��˶*j�����ཧ:+�491?�L�O�/0] q��%���9��-'�j��zz�Ze,���uN|?莝aZt��V��kO��ǃQ�h�:������E ��l��3���f*��'�r�VI�Z�R��v�p�����#�Ø�b š�pg$zy��-���2��őv ��FQ�6��t���

get_product_links.php Contains (Sucessfull Execution after first Request ):
This file generating Simple HTML response using Database result.
Response :

```
<b><div align='center' style='width:569px;color:#003486;' >myproduct</b> &nbsp;<a data-lightview-options="skin: 'light', width: 500" data-lightview-type="iframe" class="lightview rightmost" href="myorder.php" style="text-decoration:none" >
<button type="button">ADD NEW ORDER</button>
</a></div>
<b>
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: share get_product_links.php file code.

Comment: can you post a subsequent request, which is successfull

Comment: Dear, This is the content and sucessfull request result of get_product_links.php

<b><div align='center' style='width:569px;color:#003486;' >myproduct</b> &nbsp;<a data-lightview-options="skin: 'light', width: 500" data-lightview-type="iframe" class="lightview rightmost" href="myorder.php" style="text-decoration:none" >
<button type="button">ADD NEW ORDER</button>
</a></div>
<b>

Answer (score 0):

Adding an html dataType may help with this encoding issue.

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "get_product_links.php?product_id="+productval,
  dataType: "html",
  success: function(data){
    jQuery('#prodcut_links').html(data);
    jQuery('#product_title').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: After Adding dataType: "html" i am getting header Response + Result. Here is the response i am getting .
�HTTP/1.1 200 OK Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2013 04:02:35 GMT Server: Apache Vary: Accept-Encoding Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=28 Connection: Keep-Alive Transfer-Encoding: chunked Content-Type: text/html 64e
   <Correct Result Response>

Comment: As others have requested, it would be helpful to see what the code is in `get_product_links.php`.

Comment: get_products_links.php Part-1

<?php
 if(isset($_REQUEST['product_id'])) {
  $productid = $_REQUEST['product_id'];
 } else {
  $productid = "";
 }
 ?>
 
 
<?php include 'dbconnect.php'; 
$pname[0] = "Order Manager";
if($productid) { 
$query = "SELECT ProductName from product where ProductID ='".$productid."'";
$rsSearchResults = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
$pname = mysql_fetch_row($rsSearchResults); 

}
echo "<b><div align='center' style='width:569px;color:#003486;' >".$pname[0].'</b>';
?>

Comment: get_products_links.php Part-2

&nbsp;<a data-lightview-options="skin: 'light', width: 500" data-lightview-type="iframe" class="lightview rightmost" href="../phpscripts/editorder-new.php?id=new&productid=<?=$productid?>" style="text-decoration:none" >
<button type="button">ADD NEW ORDER</button>
</a></div>
<b>


<?php
//Getting Link from Products Links table



if($productid) { 
 $query ="SELECT * FROM  ProductLinks WHERE ProductID =".$productid." ORDER BY ID ASC";
 $rsSearchResults = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: get_products_links.php Part-3

 while ($pname = mysql_fetch_array($rsSearchResults)) { 
  echo '<div style="color:#0065BD;  text-align: center; float:left; padding-left:25px; padding-top:2px; padding-bottom:2px;"> <button><a href="'.$pname['LINK'].'" target="_new">'.$pname['Name_of_LINK'].'</a></button></div>';
 } 
}
?>
</b>
</div>

Comment: @user2138295 if you want to put that in a gist I'll take a closer look at it, but by the look of things you don't have anything that you're definitively returning as html or otherwise. That will likely cause you some issues.